# can't click a link if parent div is hidden on .blur()

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, click

I have links inside #anotherdiv

but by design #anotherdiv is hidden when #thediv is deselected.

When i click a link how can i get it to trigger before the parent div is hidden?

thanks!

```
$('#thediv').livequery("blur", function(e){
             $('#anotherdiv').hide();
});
```

Comment: please post basic markup/JS/CSS

Answer (score 0):

You might try to delay the `hide()` a bit:

```
$('#thediv').livequery("blur", function(e){
    setTimeout(function() { $('#anotherdiv').hide() }, 50);
});
```